# Data storage for an app that supports iCloud sync (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I'm going to program a simple iOS diary app that saves photos from camera and stores notes with date/time. All the data must be stored on user's device, but I also would like to implement iCloud backup/restore. I'm new to Swift and don't really know which technology should I use for persistence: CoreData, SQLite or maybe something else?

Comment: The best way to store data depends on the details of how you expect to use that data. So yes, Core Data, or SQLite, or maybe something else.

Comment: @TomHarrington Regarding the usage: user must be able to create, read, edit and delete notes and add/remove images to notes. It should be also possible to create note templates, add date/time. And it also should be possible to backup/restore all this info in/from iCloud.